# Selenium webdriver firefox dosent work after update

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

```
from settings import PROXY_SETTINGS
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import traceback


def initiate_driver():
    try:
        myProxy = PROXY_SETTINGS
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX["proxy"] = {
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
        "httpProxy": myProxy,
        "sslProxy": myProxy,
        "noProxy": [],
        }
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        remoteGeckoPath = "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver"
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=remoteGeckoPath, options=options)
        #driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
        return driver
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print(e)
```

I'am getting this error,
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Host header doesn't match server localhost:55419` 
when trying to create a firefox web driver.
I have tried searching the web for answers, but with no luck.
This code was working with the earlier versions of geckodriver and selenium, but after the upgrade, this happens.

Using selenium 4.0.0
Using firefox-geckodriver 0.30.0

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace

Comment: I had the same issue, but I used `'browserstack.selenium_version': '4.0.0-alpha-2'`, now with `'browserstack.selenium_version': '4.0.0'` I didn't get the error.